# Deciding between various methods for authentication in Angular 4

Tags: angular, jwt

I have read two tutorials of implementing Authentication in Angular 4.

The [first](http://tphangout.com/angular-2-authentication/) one overrides the ***RouterOutlet*** class, and declare public routes, where the login is not required.

However, the [second](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial) approach is to use  ***canActivate*** AuthGuard Interface provided by Angular 4.
I am struggling to find out which approach is the correct or efficient one to implement.

Moreover, how can I implement authorization in Angular 4.  I read about ***canActivateChild*** interface, but it seems too complicated.

Comment: The second approach will work best, You can add guards directly in the routes file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written two Guards, one for implementing the Authentication and the other one for Authorization.

```
//Guard for Authentication
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private router: Router) { }
    canActivate() {
      if(this.loginService.isLoggedIn()){
        return true;
      }
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      return false;
    }
}

//Guard for Authorization
@Injectable()
export class AdminAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private router: Router) { }
    canActivate() {
      return this.loginService.checkSession().map(res=>{
            let resJSON = res.json();
            let isAllowed = (resJSON.length > 0 && resJSON[0].authority === "ROLE_ADMIN") ? true : (this.router.navigate(['/home']), false);
            return isAllowed;
          });
    }
}
```

Is this Implementation correct, or should I follow some other? (Although its working fine, but I am looking for a better approach).
The routing file for my application is as follows:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'adminPage',
        component: MyAccountComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard, AdminAuthGuard] 
    }
];
```

So, whenever I am logged in as the administrator, I can access the ***adminPage***, whereas, if I login as a normal user, I am not able to access the webpage.

The loginService has been implemented as follows:

```
//Login Service
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  private serverPath:string = AppConst.serverPath; //'http://127.0.0.1:8888'
  constructor(private http:Http, private router:Router) { }
  isLoggedIn() {
      return localStorage.getItem('xAuthToken') !== null;
    }
  //Server will send back the Token for the user.   
  sendCredential(username: string, password: string) {
    let url = this.serverPath+'/token';
    let encodedCredentials = btoa(username+":"+password);
    let basicHeader = "Basic "+encodedCredentials;
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization' : basicHeader
    });
    return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers});
  }
  //Server returns a JSONARRAY respresenting the roles of the user.
  checkSession() {
    let url = this.serverPath+'/checkSession';
    let headers = new Headers({
        'x-auth-token' : localStorage.getItem('xAuthToken')
    });
    return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers});
  }
  logout() {
    let url = this.serverPath+'/user/logout';
    let headers = new Headers({
        'x-auth-token' : localStorage.getItem('xAuthToken')
    });
    return this.http.post(url, '', {headers: headers});
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems fine. You can create separate files for both services so that you won't get confused moving ahead with them.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [AuthGuard](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate).

Following is a simple example how you can implement AuthGuard.

**Module.ts**

```
// Routes
const routes : Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate : [AuthService] //<== Activate AuthGuard
},
{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
},
{
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: ''
}
];
'

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent
    ],
    providers: [AuthService], //<== Add AuthService here
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**AuthService**

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot }    from '@angular/router';

@Injectable() 
export class AuthService implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        let url: string = state.url; //<== Get URL if needed

        if (localStorage.getItem('token')) { // <== Check for token
            return true;
        }else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice and code. I have added two guards, one for authorization and the other one for authentication. I am not sure whether my implementation is correct or not?  I have provided the code for my implementation in the Answer. Is that implementation correct or should I change it some how? (I am using session at backend, not jwt).